# At edit in webgrid in mvc3 why ModelState.IsValid is false as condition is true?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SecurityMappingModel objModel)
{

    //edit code

    if (objModel.Id != Guid.Empty)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            mappings = (List<SecurityMappingModel>)Session["Mappings"];
            var objRemove = mappings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == objModel.Id);
            if (objRemove != null)
            {
                mappings.Remove(objRemove);
                mappings.Add(objModel);
                ViewBag.Mappings = mappings;
            }
            Session["Mappings"] = mappings;
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

inside objModel one of the field is having value 0 as it is a textfield i'm putting value into it but inside Controller oject objModel showing that field value is zero :( :( why???

Comment: Can you show us what `SecurityMappingModel` looks like and also show us your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one of your model values is not valid. You should be able to find out which one by looking at the items in ModelState.Values. Each item has an Errors property.
The result of this line should contain at least one item:

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.Where(value=>value.Errors.Any());
```

Comment: At time of edit `3rd field that is Calculation is coming 0 but why ?` :( i'm new plz help...

Comment: inside objModel one of the field is having value 0 as it is a textfield i'm putting value into it but inside Controller oject objModel showing that field value is zero :( :( why???

Comment: It's really hard to tell without more information. Can you put the relevant view code and the model class in your start post?